# pymongo "[Errno -5] No address associated with hostname" fixed, but why?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using this code with a somewhat older version of PyMongo (I believe it was 3.5 or 3.6):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@myhost.com/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
db = client['db_name']
collection = db['collection_name']

for document in collection.find():
    # do stuff with document
```

I was getting this error on the `collection.find()` call:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: myhost.com:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

After upgrading to PyMongo 3.11 and using `mongodb+srv://` in the db connect string, the error went away.

My question is: Why?  "No address associated with hostname" seems like a DNS-level error.  Why did a simple library upgrade fix it?

Answer (score 3):

1. You changed the URI.
2. All software has issues, maybe you found one.